# Overwrite ftp files using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, teamcity

The problem is my code is not overwriting all files

I have used this script earlier, it does upload files and overwrites some of them but not overwrite all of them.

```
# Get publishing profile for the web app
$webappname = "sib"
$resourceGroup = "sib2"
$appdirecotry = "c:\temp\sib"
$xml = [xml](Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile -Name $webappname `
-ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
-OutputFile null)
$xml = [xml]$xml
# Extract connection information from publishing profile
$username = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userName").value
$password = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userPWD").value
$url = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@publishUrl").value
Write-Host "Set a virtual application"
Set-Location $appdirectory
$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $appdirectory -Recurse #| Where-Object{!($_.PSIsContainer)}
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $relativepath = (Resolve-Path -Path $file.FullName -Relative).Replace('\', '/')
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri("$url/$relativepath")
    if($file.PSIsContainer)
    {
        $uri.AbsolutePath + "is Directory"
        $ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($uri);
        $ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::MakeDirectory
        $ftprequest.UseBinary = $true
        #$ftprequest.UsePassive = $true
        #$ftprequest.KeepAlive = $false

        $ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)

        $response = $ftprequest.GetResponse();
        $response.StatusDescription
        continue
    }
    "Uploading to " + $uri.AbsoluteUri
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $file.FullName)
} 
$webclient.Dispose()
```

It does not overwrite all files

Comment: WebClient.UploadFile method uses the FTP STOR command internally.So it will replace the file ideally. Can you try adding Exception handling block or logs , just to see if you URI is correct as sometime it happens that URI fromed by combining BaseAddress is invalida and it throws WebException.

Comment: Mohit i have tried it. it overwrites most of the files. but few files are not getting overwritten

Comment: Also, it has directories inside, so it starts with creating directories through an error file unavailable then after directories, it throws login issue, and then again logs in and upload remaining files.

Comment: the problem is those directories already exist. so that is why it throws exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be more good.

```
function DeleteFtpFolder($url, $credentials)
{
    $listRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $listRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectoryDetails
    $listRequest.Credentials = $credentials

    $lines = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    $listResponse = $listRequest.GetResponse()
    $listStream = $listResponse.GetResponseStream()
    $listReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($listStream)

    while (!$listReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        $line = $listReader.ReadLine()
        $lines.Add($line) | Out-Null
    }

    $listReader.Dispose()
    $listStream.Dispose()
    $listResponse.Dispose()

    foreach ($line in $lines)
    {
        $tokens = $line.Split(" ", 5, [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

        $type = $tokens[2]
        $name = $tokens[3]
        $fileUrl = ($url + "/" + $name)

        if ($type -eq "<DIR>")
        {
            Write-Host "Found folder: $name"

            DeleteFtpFolder $fileUrl $credentials

            Write-Host "Deleting folder: $name"
            $deleteRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($fileUrl)
            $deleteRequest.Credentials = $credentials
            $deleteRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::RemoveDirectory
            $deleteRequest.GetResponse() | Out-Null
        }
        else 
        {
            $fileUrl = ($url + "/" + $name)
            Write-Host "Deleting file: $name"

            $deleteRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($fileUrl)
            $deleteRequest.Credentials = $credentials
            $deleteRequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::DeleteFile
            $deleteRequest.GetResponse() | Out-Null
        }
    }
}

$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
DeleteFtpFolder $url $credentials


Set-Location $appdirectory
$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $appdirectory -Recurse #| Where-Object{!($_.PSIsContainer)}
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $relativepath = (Resolve-Path -Path $file.FullName -Relative).Replace('\', '/')
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri("$url/$relativepath")
    if($file.PSIsContainer)
    {
        $uri.AbsolutePath + "is Directory"
        $ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($uri);
        $ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::MakeDirectory
        $ftprequest.UseBinary = $true
        #$ftprequest.UsePassive = $true
        #$ftprequest.KeepAlive = $false

        $ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)

        $response = $ftprequest.GetResponse();
        $response.StatusDescription
        continue
    }
    "Uploading to " + $uri.AbsoluteUri
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $file.FullName)
} 
$webclient.Dispose()
```

Comment: In my case url is the siteroot, in case to add folder name, add foldername like this:

$foldertodelete = $url + "/foldertodelete"

pass $foldertodelete instead of $url in order to delete folder from ftp

Answer (score 0):

I have to use the above code in CI/CD Process. So if it is first time done the above script is fine but it wont work correctly in overwrite scenario of ftp.

if i have to overwrite, my script is changed. so i have 2 scripts in place now. one for first time environment, one is for overwrite environment

instead of the following in overwrite script

```
Set-Location $appdirectory
$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $appdirectory -Recurse #| Where-Object{!($_.PSIsContainer)}
     foreach ($file in $files)
    {
        $relativepath = (Resolve-Path -Path $file.FullName -Relative).Replace('\', '/')
        $uri = New-Object System.Uri("$url/$relativepath")
        if($file.PSIsContainer)
        {
            $uri.AbsolutePath + "is Directory"
            $ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($uri);
            $ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::MakeDirectory
            $ftprequest.UseBinary = $true
            #$ftprequest.UsePassive = $true
            #$ftprequest.KeepAlive = $false

            $ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)

            $response = $ftprequest.GetResponse();
            $response.StatusDescription
            continue
        }
        "Uploading to " + $uri.AbsoluteUri
        $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $file.FullName)
    } 
    $webclient.Dispose()
```

I am using the following in overwrite script

```
    Set-Location $appdirectory
$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $appdirectory -Recurse | Where-Object{!($_.PSIsContainer)}
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $relativepath = (Resolve-Path -Path $file.FullName -Relative).Replace(".\", "").Replace('\', '/')
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri("$url/$relativepath")
    "Uploading to " + $uri.AbsoluteUri
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $file.FullName)
} 
$webclient.Dispose()
```

The above works like a charm for overwrite scenarios. But let me confirm you, this wont work in first time setup. it will throw 550 error if you try this time in first time.